# Replace nested expressions using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How would you only replace the x that are between bracket in the expression below:

```
{ x} x {x } x x {} x{x}{  x}
```

Comment: Is there only a single x at a time between brackets or it is possible to have several x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Without preserving spaces inside the braces

You can use `.gsub` with both a look-behind and a look-ahead operator:

```
# replace all instances of x within curly braces with y
'{ x} x {x } x x {} x{x}{  x}'.gsub(/(?<={)\s*x\s*(?=})/, 'y')
```

Output:

```
"{y} x {y} x x {} x{y}{y}"
```

### Preserving spaces inside the braces

You will need an slightly alternate approach to preserving spaces:

```
'{ x} x {x } x x {} x{x}{  x}'.gsub(/{(\s*)x(\s*)}/, '{\1y\2}')
```

Output:

```
"{ y} x {y } x x {} x{y}{  y}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
txt.gsub(/(?:\G(?!\A)|{(?=[^{}]*}))[^x}]*\Kx/, 'y')
```

It works with several x too.

details:

```
(?:
    \G           # position after the last match
    (?!\A)       # prevent to match the start of the string
  |              # OR
    {            # an opening curly bracket
    (?=[^{}]*})  # ensure there is a closing curly bracket
)
[^x}]*           # all that is not an x or a }
\K               # remove all on the left from match result
x                # literal x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '{ x} x {x } x x {} x{x}{  x}'    
str.gsub /{\s*x\s*}/, '{z}'
```

and http://rubular.com/

This solution does not preserve the spaces.