# Replace nested expression using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How would you only replace the x that are between bracket in the expression below, while still preserving spaces and other letters:

```
{ x} x {abc x efg} x x {} { x{x}{  x} }
```

Different from [Replace nested expressions using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179838/replace-nested-expressions-using-ruby) because you have brackets inside brackets.

Comment: The easiest way is to match the outer most bracketed expression with recursive regex, then do mass replacement in the replacement callback function.

Comment: If your real-world task is any more complicated, you may want to consider creating a parser for the given grammar using Parslet, Citrus, or TreeTop. Those are probably overkill if this is just a one-off task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (with regex) is to match the outer most bracketed expressions, and then replace `x` in the replacement callback:

```
> '{ x} x {abc x efg} x x {} { x{x}{  x} }'.gsub(/\{(?:[^{}]|\g<0>)*\}/) {|s| s.gsub('x', 'y')}
=> "{ y} x {abc y efg} x x {} { y{y}{  y} }"
```

The core of this solution is in this regex to match the outer most bracketed expression:

```
/\{(?:[^{}]|\g<0>)*\}/
```

Throwing away the `\g<0>` branch for a moment, we have `\{(?:[^{}]­)*\}`. This will match `{` followed by any number of characters that is not `{` or `}`, then `}`.

`\g<0>` will recurse into the whole expression itself. This adds the possibility that between `{` and `}`, it can contain any number of bracketed expressions, which in turn can contain non-bracket-characters and more bracketed expressions.

The regex above will match `{ x}`, `{abc x efg}`, `{}`, `{ x{x}{­  x} }` from the string, then you can replace these `x` inside the replacement callback.

I'm not sure, but I don't think there is anyway to do this without a replacement callback. Even if there is, it would not be a practical solution.